# Retrofitting a Dobsonian Reflecting Telescope for smart phones?

Tags: telescope, orion

Just received an old [Orion Deep Space Explorer 6" Dobsonian Reflecting Telescope](https://cl.ly/3j0s2m2V351d/29049_6-98.pdf).  I'm hoping to gift it to my kids, but I want to add a twist...

We have a microscope with an adapter for an iPhone that has been great fun with allowing time lapse photography and very nice images on large monitors, so I wanted to accomplish something similar with this device.  Telescopes, in the past, have always been a dud due to the lack of multiple kids and family members wanting to be able to see the display simultaneously.

Has anyone had any experience at retrofitting a unit such as this with an adapter that has given good results?  Any gotchas to be aware of?

I'm eying the "[HookUpz 2.0 Universal Smartphone Optics Digiscoping Adapter](http://carson.com/products/digiscoping-hookupz2-is-200/)", but a little worried as I've never retrofitted such a device before and would like to hit this spot on since the timeframe is tight for me.

Comment: What do you want to photograph?  Are you aware that, unlike a microscope, the subject matter moves? Dobsonians do not typically have equatorial mounts.

Comment: Hmm, this both rotates and has a vertical axis. Am I missing something about moving it? From a 3D perspective, this seems to cover all axes of motion required to track, albeit not the most fine tracking and certainly not automated...